# Scheduler library in C++ similar to Java Quartz

Tags: c++, scheduler

I'm looking for a cross-platform library in C/C++ which can schedule jobs, function calls, etc. It would be nice if it is closer to Java Quartz. I would prefer BSD style licenses, LGPL would be okay too.

Comment: Have you considered using Quartz itself in your C++ application using the invocation API to load the VM, and JNA or JNI to call C code from a Quartz job?

Comment: unless the app is already under a JVM this could be horrible for the app's footprint and deployability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libevent: http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/ is probably too heavyweight for your use case, but you can decide for yourself if it works for you.

**Edit:** This is more about scheduling functions after certain timeouts within a program. Looking at Quartz, it appears to be broader. So I doubt if libevent is what you are looking for.